# Python Read csv file from URL without “csv” suffix

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I'm trying to download a csv file from an url without the "csv" suffix.
The url is: 
https://www.ishares.com/de/professionelle-anleger/de/produkte/270048/ishares-msci-world-value-factor-ucits-etf/1478358465952.ajax?fileType=csv&fileName=IS3S_holdings&dataType=fund&asOfDate=20180731

Since there is no "csv" suffix I haven't found any solution for this problem.   My current code looks like this:

```
link = "https://www.ishares.com/de/professionelle-anleger/de/produkte/270048/ishares-msci-world-value-factor-ucits-etf/1478358465952.ajax?fileType=csv&fileName=IS3S_holdings&dataType=fund&asOfDate=20180731"
data = pd.read_csv(link)
```

Any help is really appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: what version of pandas are you using

Comment: Are you sure issue is with URL or filename...? Have you tried downloading the file and opening it from your local disk?

Comment: Have you tried using the request package to download the CSV, and then import to pandas data frame?

Comment: URL mentioned return HTML instead of csv

Comment: Hi, Can you please post the correct link? and in future please make sure you post the correct link.

Comment: Hi, @PiyushBaderia the link is correct. I just double checked it.

Comment: @j.DOE are you sure the link to download the csv file does not require authentication? That might be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look into the file. There's a header line before the data starts. Skiprows can help.

```
data = pd.read_csv(link, skiprows=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code I tried :

```
import urllib2

link = "https://www.ishares.com/de/professionelle-anleger/de/produkte/270048/ishares-msci-world-value-factor-ucits-etf/1478358465952.ajax?fileType=csv&fileName=IS3S_holdings&dataType=fund&asOfDate=20180731"
local_file_name = 'test.csv'
u = urllib2.urlopen(link)
f = open(local_file_name, 'wb')
meta = u.info()

file_size_dl = 0
block_sz = 8192
while True:
    buffer = u.read(block_sz)
    if not buffer:
        break
    file_size_dl += len(buffer)
    f.write(buffer)

f.close()
```

Code executes an `urlopen` call to download the URL. Curiosly, the file it yields is an html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" lang="de" xml:lang="de">
<head>
<title>iShares by BlackRock - Führender ETF Anbieter weltweit</title>
<link type="image/x-icon" href="//assets.blackrock.com/uk-retail-assets/ishares-
```

However, opening the same URL with a web browser allows to get the csv data... that csv, you can read it with pandas and

```
 data = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=2, header=1)
```